# Get selected values from 5 combo boxes

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have 3 drop downs, but it can change. It is dynamic drop down

[image]

How can I get all selected values in those drop downs?

Comment: You may do it by iterating throw them with a `for` loop. If you use jQuery, you can get their value using `$(comboItem).val()` if not you can use `comboItem.options[comboItem.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: @AhmadManouchehri can u explain it through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an explanation of my comment..
Run the snippet to check it in action

```js
var combos = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="select"]');

function getvalues() {
  
  // Clear shown data
  console.clear();

  for (var i=0; i < combos.length; i++) {
    // Get selected option value
    var option = combos[i].options[combos[i].selectedIndex]; 
    
    // Show options
    console.log(combos[i].name + " ::  " + option.value + " : " + option.text);
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="select-1">
  <option value="1" selected>First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="select-2">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="select-3">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Third</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getvalues()">Get values</button>
```